# Deploy web application that has a .data-00000-of-00001

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, github, chatbot

I have a django project that is basically a API for a chatbot, the chatbot uses tensorflow and it uses a extremely large file that ends in .data-00000-of-00001. I can not upload it to github because it is really big. Anyone knows how can I deploy my web application with this kind of file?

Comment: Describing your use case (django, tensorflow, some output file for a chatbot project) might help, but the most important piece of information is the size of your file. Git has LFS, large file storage, which may help you, but only to a certain size: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-12-increased-git-large-file-storage-limits/

Comment: I have already tried to track it using Git LFS but it does not seem to recognize the file. I dont know if I need to put that extension or what.

Comment: Added some instructions for git-lfs to an answer below, as well as how to configure github with lfs. Cheers

Comment: If you have a specific error log from trying to do the installation steps I've listed below, edit your question and add it for context.

Comment: Generally, Git is not the best place to store large files, especially binaries. Unless you intend to edit that file in the future and track the changes between versions of it and can't use somewhere else outside of Git, I would look into storing it elsewhere outside of your repo.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you or not, but conceptually, a deployment is "Copy some files from location A to location B." At the end of your deployment script, envision an additional line: "Copy data file from location X to location B." And if you never update that data file, you may not even need to automate it; perhaps you could copy it one time manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size of your file, and the plan you have purchased for Github, there are different max file sizes:

https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage

```
Product Maximum file size
GitHub Free 2 GB
GitHub Pro  2 GB
GitHub Team 4 GB
GitHub Enterprise Cloud 5 GB
```

If your file is smaller than the corresponding max file size for your plan, you can add git-lfs by following the instructions here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files/installing-git-large-file-storage

And then configure your github repo to use git-lfs by following the instructions here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files/configuring-git-large-file-storage

If your file is larger than the file sizes mentioned here, you'll likely want to host it from a cloud service like Google's Cloud Storage.

Comment: I already have tried but when I run git lfs track "*.data-00000-of-00001'" it says that the system could not find the file. I have tried using the absolute and relative paths but no luck.

Comment: Please add the error messages you are getting to your question, as well as what commands returned those errors.

Comment: When I do git lfs track "*.data-00000-of-00001" I get: Error: CreateFile C:\Users\Diego\Documents\Programaci�n: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
This operation must be run in a work tree.

Comment: I have also tried "chatbot\modelo_pesos\modelo_pesos.data-00000-of-00001" which is the relative path to the file, but I get the same error.